# Is it possible to chain overrided method call from top to bottom?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Suppose I have this hierarchy of classes

```
class Parent {
    protected List<Object> things = new List<Object>;

    public Parent() {
        things.addAll(declareThings());
    }

    public List<Object> declareThings() {
        // things declaration
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public List<Object> declareThings() {
        // additional things declaration
    }
}

class GrandChild extends Child {
    
    public List<Object> declarThings() {
        // addtional things
    }
}
```

I would like that creating an instance of say GrandChild, I get all the declared `things` in the hierarchy. Is it possible to implement such behaviour?

Comment: With ```protected``` access modifier you can operate on ```things``` collection from subclasses instances.

Comment: You already have access to `things` in the subclass since it is protected.

Comment: I know that I have access to things. But I would like that each class declares its own objects that are going to be added to  the ones specified up in the hierarchy

Comment: It's normally considered a bad idea to call overridable methods in a constructor. It can lead to confusing behaviour with partially initialised objects.

Comment: thank you I didn't know that...why my linter doesn't say nothing?!

Answer (score 2):

For each subclass, add a constructor where the first instruction is `super();`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, and the subclasses already have constructors where the first thing is `super();` -- that's what Java generates by default.